# I wrongly emailed a professor from a personal email, should I send the email again from my institutional email or wait?

Tags: application, email, international-students, internship

I was writing to a professor from another university about the possibility of an internship in his lab, but I thought I sent it from my university email only to later realize I sent it from my personal Gmail. I sent it this morning and have not gotten a reply, should I send it again from my university email or wait? What should I do?

Comment: I don't see any problem sending email from personal email id. Please a week at least before sending a follow up email. This is my experience

Answer (score 6):

There is no particular need to use your university email when contacting professors at other institutions, as it doesn't really convey any meaningful information to them. (The situation is different when emailing people at your own institution, where it helps to identify and authenticate you if you use your university email.)

Re-sending the email risks making you appear impatient and/or entitled.

Do note that cold-call emails about internships have very high chances of being ignored anyway. I wouldn't expect a response at all here.

Comment: Emailing from proudplagiarist@evilstudent.org might not be a good idea, though. Otherwise, good advice.